# Can users of main AP access WiFi extender with different SSID?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wireless-extender

Network:

- Router has SSID: AP1
- WiFi extender/booster has SSID: AP2
- (therefore two different SSIDs)
- Router and extender has the same WPA passwords (the only possible setting in the extender)

**Question:** Since they have different SSID is there a way for devices connected to AP1/router to know that the AP2/extender is extending AP1/router? (and automatically use extender if its signal is stronger?)

---

In the general sense it seems like it's not possible but I'm wondering if the wireless protocol can know since they havethe same passwords.

SSIDs aren't really AP1 and AP2. It's just for this example. There's really something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it won't happen automatically. Clients only automatically roam to APs publishing the same SSID with the same security type and password. Other SSIDs will look like other networks.